# Access denied for wordpress wp-admin/post.php while POST method

Tags: wordpress, apache, httpd.conf

I am getting this error while uploading content to wordpress.

Access Denied

You don't have permission to access 'http://example.com/xxx/wp-admin/post.php

Below is the .htaccess.

```
cat /var/www/html/insurance-investment-knowledge/.htaccess 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /insurance-investment-knowledge/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /insurance-investment-knowledge/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I checked for mod security but it is not installed on the system, so I think adding will not make any difference

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Please suggest how I can resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Disable all of your plugins and try again. If the POST request is processed normally, chances are at least one of your plugins is causing the issue.

Comment: @cabrerahector could you please share the steps to disable the plugins?

Comment: Dashboard > Plugins > Select All > Bulk Actions > Deactivate.

Comment: I haven't disabled the plugins yet but this issue is causing whenever the content limit is high in post method. For shorter content its working fine. Please help me if there is a solution for this.